# How to can i use jQuery.when() to make the second call from the first cal

Tags: jquery, ajax

Jquery provides the [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) function as follow. inquiryId is in the first call

```
$.when( $.ajax( "http://localhost:50006/odata/Inquiry" ), $.ajax( "http://localhost:50006/odata/Inquiry?$filter=Id eq '" + inquiryIdFromTheFirstCall + "'" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // i want to get the id of an Inquiry from the fist call and make the second call with it 
});
```

how can i achive this?

Comment: u can use `.then()` .

Comment: how can you achieve what?

Comment: i want to get the id of an Inquiry from the fist call and make the second call with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need $.when, just use the success of the first request.

```
$.ajax( "http://localhost:50006/odata/Inquiry" ).done(function(a1) {
    $.ajax("http://localhost:50006/odata/Inquiry?$filter=Id eq '" + a1 + "'").done(function(a2) {
        // do something with a2
    });
});
```

***I hope that url param isn't being inserted directly into a sql query.***

Answer (score 0):

U can chain them using `.then` to have a call first then to go on for the second call. After fist call u can use its result in second call.

```
    $.ajax({...}).then(function(){
        return $.ajax({...});
    }).then(function(){
        return $.ajax({...});
    }).then(function(){
        return $.ajax({...});
    }).then(function(){
        return $.ajax({...});
    });
```